# One exchange with multiple routing keys or multiple exchanges efficient in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, rabbitmq-exchange

I am using RabbitMQ in my project and was wondering if I should use a single exchange with multiple routing keys or use multiple exchanges? Which would be more efficient?

Example if I use single exchange E with routing keys A,B,C and consumer connects to that exchange E and get data using A,B,C routing keys. Another option would be that I should send it to the exchange A, exchange B, exchange C with no routing keys and consumer could connect to each of the exchange for required data.

an example with python's library pika(which i am currently using):

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='E',
                      routing_key='A',
                      body=data)  
channel.basic_publish(exchange='E',
                      routing_key='B',
                      body=data)  
channel.basic_publish(exchange='E',
                      routing_key='C',
                      body=data)

OR

channel.basic_publish(exchange='A',
                      routing_key='',
                      body=data)  
channel.basic_publish(exchange='B',
                      routing_key='',
                      body=data)  
channel.basic_publish(exchange='C',
                      routing_key='',
                      body=data)
```

Comment: You want direct excange with bind to queues A,B,C?

Comment: Why not run benchmarks and see for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can go on your first approach. Declare your `exchange` as a Direct Exchange. In the case of a `Direct Exchange`, it takes the `queue` name as the `routing key`. An `exchange` is capable of binding itself to multiple queues. Also, the job of an exchange is to route the message to a queue. Having multiple queues bound to it will not decrease the efficiency of RabbitMQ.

Comment: but my question was which approach would be better ? first or second one and why prefer one over another ?